# Django has no attribute 'GeoManager' issue

Tags: django, django-models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
location = models.PointField(srid=4326,null=True,blank=True)
objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I am hosting my Django project on AWS server. I am unable to run the project because of the error I added below, but I implemented the same project in my Ubuntu system and it's working fine.

`Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f527104b6a8> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run autoreload.raise_last_exception() File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception raise _exception[1] File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)() File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate app_config.import_models() File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name) File "/home/ubuntu/django_env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/ubuntu/Sg_Bus/SgBusTransport/models.py", line 10, in <module> class BusStop(models.Model): File "/home/ubuntu/Sg_Bus/SgBusTransport/models.py", line 17, in BusStop objects = models.GeoManager() AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.gis.db.models' has no attribute 'GeoManager'`

Comment: have you tried this ? from django.contrib.gis.db.models.manager import GeoManager

Answer (score 18):

Is it possible that you are running Django 2.0?

[GeoManager has been removed.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)

A workaround that appears to function correctly as of Django 2.0:

Import in your models file:

```
from django.db.models import Manager as GeoManager
```

In your model class:

```
objects = GeoManager()
```

Now you should be able to do [spatial lookups!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#spatial-lookups)

[Credit to this django-cities pull request.](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities/pull/188)

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.manager import GeoManager
```

Also you'll want to avoid situations like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

The problem is this, you've imported two `models` modules - which one does Python use when you try to use `models.Whatever`?

Try something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
```

Comment: More accurately, only the django.contrib.gis.db import is necessary, as django.db is inherited. http://www.paolocorti.net/2009/04/01/a-day-with-geodjango/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of GeoManager you can now just use Manager

```
from django.db.models.manager import Manager
```